# API: should a problem with data be announced by a HTTP code or in the response body?

Tags: api, error-handling, error-messages, http-response

After years of (amateur, dirty) personal API development I finally decided to follow some best practices.

**My problem**: the API may have problems, say, retrieving some data. It will gracefully handle the problem but needs to pass that information back to the requester (a JS front of mine, if that matters).

**My question**: should I use some HTTP error code to inform about that problem, or send back `200` and explain in the body that there is a problem?

[Another question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/370005/restful-api-should-i-use-http-statusmessage-body-or-my-own-error-codes-in-bod) tackled the issue **for problems with the request** (i.e. - the requester sent something that was not correct). My issue is likely different because the requester sent a correct request, but it was not honored by the API (it is the fault of the API). The requester does not care about the nature of the problem, they just know that they should discard that call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annoyingly, it depends on how meaningfully the issue (in the backend) is actually considered a problem (to the end user).

Just to prove the range of possibilities:

- If a main server failed, but the failover server worked, you'd likely not even tell the user that there is a problem.
- If your endpoint is supposed to find corroborating data from many external services, and one of those was not working but the available sources still corroborated the data, you'd probably only mention in passing that "service X could not be reached", but the request itself and thus its status code shouldn't indicate an error...
- ...**unless** there is an explicit requirement in your software specs that the only way for a request to be considered successful is when *all* sources can corroborate it. Now, any absence of any external service will cause a negative HTTP status code to be returned. You might still return the incomplete data that you did receive (just to be informative), but the request itself was not completely successful.

The main idea here is to ask yourself what you want the sender of that request to do. If you want to make them aware of an issue, you return an error code. If you want them to continue on as planned, then you return a success code.

Note the **difference between a failure in the backend and a failed request**! For example, our platform has a health endpoint that you can send a request to, and it will tell you if all database servers and external services are working.
When they are not all available, the health endpoint returns a bad health report but with status code 200, because the request for health itself succeeded, regardless of the system being in bad health.
However, if the config file which contains the list of databases/services is missing, the endpoint does return a 500 because **it cannot perform the health check**, and therefore it cannot do what you asked it to do.

The status code does not indicate the content of the response, it only indicates whether the request was properly handled in the way the requester expected it to.

> It will gracefully handle the problem but needs to pass that information back to the requester (a JS front of mine, if that matters).

If by "gracefully handle" you mean that the actual request succeeds and the encountered issue is more of a "oh and by the way..." nature instead of a "this is the reason I couldn't do what you asked", then I agree that the HTTP status code should not indicate an error.

> Another question tackled the issue for problems with the request (i.e. - **the requester sent something that was not correct**). My issue is likely different because the requester sent a correct request, but it was not honored by the API (**it is the fault of the API**).

The bolded parts are inherently orthogonal as far as HTTP status codes are concerned.

- 4xx status codes are errors which blame the sender of the request
- 5xx status code are errors in which the server blames itself

It helps to consider the meaning of these two different responses.

- 5xx errors mean that the server made a mistake somewhere. As an end user, you can likely expect that someone will fix the server at some point, and therefore you can eventually **retry the same request**.
- 4xx errors mean that the request you sent to the server is unusable. Either it violates some basic contract, it's not legible, or it refers to something that plain doesn't exist. In all of these cases, as an end user you are being told that **retrying this same request is pointless**.

These are broad strokes. Anyone can come up with a fringe exception whereby retrying coincidentally does/n't work, but that's beside the main point.

*"it was not honored by the API"* implies to me that the backend considers this a well-formed but "dishonorable" request that the backend actively refuses to engage in, therefore suggesting the error code belongs to the 4xx range.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is: If your API method cannot completely fulfill its job, it has to inform the caller, and typically by using the established way of communicating failure, being the HTTP status code in your case of a web API.

But the expression "fulfill its job" needs interpretation.

We build APIs to create the language that our callers want to use to solve their problems, so we should take on the caller's point of view. In this context, you wrote

> The requester does not care about the nature of the problem, they just
> know that they should discard that call.

meaning that the job is to do something completely and not to try something and report about the degree of compliance. Running into some internal problems and e.g. returning only a subset of the correct result does not count as success, as far as I understand you.

Sending them a "successful" 200 status code and forcing them to analyze the result body is certainly not what they'd expect and prefer. They have to check for status codes anyway, so using that mechanism is straightforward.

TL;DR Send an error HTTP status code, and if you like, add a body describing the failure reason so the requester has useful information for logging purposes.